# How to vertically align makeup page in ConTeXt?

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, context-mkiv

I have a minimal example

```
\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[dejavusans]

\definemakeup[titlepage]

\starttext

\startmakeup[titlepage]

{\tfd Title at top}

\stopmakeup[titlepage]

\stoptext
```

`Title at top` must be at top of page, but it is vertically centered. How to control vertical alignment of makeup page ?

I need `startmekaup` because I dont want page numbering on this page.

Comment: This is not what you asked about, but always use `{\tfd\setupinterlinespace ....\endgraf}` to get proper interline spacing for titles longer than one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makeups [by default use](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/6091f1997cb58861ee2d0c2b9000430e8238b631%3atex/context/base/page-mak.mkvi#L167-186) `top=\vss` and `bottom=\vss` which vertically center the content. You can override those values as follows. To set the font size you can use the `style` parameter.

```
\definemakeup
  [titlepage]
  [top=,
   bottom=,
   style=\tfd]
```